# How to print tab in log message?

Tags: java, tabs, log4j, slf4j

If I write something like

```
LOGGER.error("123 \t 456");
```

It prints as `123 \t 456`

I expect to see tab.

Comment: Try replacing \t with \u0009

Comment: @VortixDev also doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the logger method using
`Logger.error([arg1],[args...],[args...]);`
Likewise, 
`Logger.error("123","\t","456");`
It will print `123     456` in console.
http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html

Comment: Looks too complicated